# How to use xpath attribute in odoo 10?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

i want to learn Odoo xml but a don't understand a lot of things specially on xpath, for example :

```
<xpath exp="//field[@name='is_done']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisibl">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

what is **attribute**, how it's work, and what mean the value **1** inside the attribute tag

and if do you have guys some resources to learn more that's great

finally thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need three skills to successfully work with xml in Odoo:

1. Xml basics.
2. Xpath basics.
3. Knowledge of the way Odoo uses xml and xpath.

Xml and Xpath are standards and you can find lots of tutorials and references for these. A simple xml learning resource is https://www.w3schools.com/xml/.
You can find also Xpath material from same site at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp. When you know basics in xml and xpath, you have a good position to learn how to use xml in Odoo.

Odoo uses xml in multiple places, e.g. Qweb templates, module data files and view definitions. You can learn these from Odoo Developer documentation at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/index.html:

- Data files: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/data.html
- Qweb reports: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html
- Odoo views: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/views.html

Data files are plain xml in Odoo specific structure. Qweb reports use a templating language implemented in xml to build reports and views.

Odoo view inheritance uses xpath to locate places is parent document to modify the inherited view. To specifically learn Odoo xpath, take a close look at the Inheritance Specs at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/views.html#inheritance-specs. The use of attribute is explained there in attributes section.

For editing xml directly in Odoo database you can use the editor in Odoo. This is available for xml fields, e.g. when editing views. It is not fancy, but it can format xml documents and validate that the xml is valid when you save it. For xml data in your modules, you can use other tools, e.g. VisualStudio Code.

Xml is an important part in Odoo architecture. When you master Xml and know how Odoo uses it, you can easily utilize development and customization capatilities in Odoo.

Answer (score 1):

i would to recommend this document

https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/xml/index.html

your code not correct
so the correct code should be like this

```
<xpath exp="//field[@name='is_done']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: And it should be `invisible`